# Why are is IndexOrDocValuesQuery taking so long?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using a 5 node elasticsearch cluster with a ~120GB index.

We are having issues with slow queries that have several filters. After profiling our queries, I see that IndexOrDocValuesQuery is taking about 3.2 seconds each. Each query has about 4 or 5 of these steps which cause it to take 20 seconds. What is weird is that the TermQuery which I would imagine is much more expensive takes 64 ms.

Where should we poke around to get more information as to what could be slowing these queries down?

Elasticsearch V5.5, I think there are like 280M documents but 40M primary documents (without nested)

Node Specs:
4 CPUs
26 GB RAM
12 GB Heap

5 Data Nodes, 2 Masters, 2 Clients. Masters and clients are much lower speced than nodes.

Here is the query: https://gist.github.com/wakawaka54/d4cad864d858efc41a0b2806ea0041b4 1

Here is the query profile result: https://gist.github.com/wakawaka54/6b52fd0eef2b8ead1589241e65c239fe

Here is the index mapping:
https://gist.github.com/wakawaka54/417602c8f73a613830904b20398b7bac

Comment: of course term query is faster, that's no doubt. will you accept explanation of this as an answer?

Comment: Well is there anything I could try to speed up these range queries, like force caching on these fields or something. Or is it possible the disk speed isn't as fast as it should be? It's just weird because all together the cluster has more RAM than the size of the index so I think something must definitely be wrong for these queries to still take 20 seconds

Comment: could you share your mappings?

Comment: Yes, here you go, index mapping: https://gist.github.com/wakawaka54/417602c8f73a613830904b20398b7bac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First regarding **term query** vs any other queries. Term queries are the fastest, cause they require only lookup by term and getting all matched doc ids. It's a trivial operation and it is utilizing term dictionary where this information taken as fast as key lookup.

Of course ranged filter would be much more slow, even if you have DocValues enabled (by default) it still will be slower.

I don't see that your `numberSort` is of nested type. Not sure, if it will speedup search, but worth trying, since you want it to be nested, I think.

What could be done to speed up the queries:

- You already select those range queries as a filters, which should [cache](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/filter-caching.html#_independent_query_caching) them, so later it could be reused efficiently (so, I hope you measure numbers after **warming** up)
- From the size of your index it's clear that if you're dividing **120 Gb** of index into 5 nodes you will get around **24 Gb** per data node. However, you RAM is only **26 Gb**, which isn't enough to [mmap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mmap) all indices files to be located in the memory (you only have 26 - 12 = **14 Gb** of RAM for mmap). This situation will require to load/unload files from the disk into memory, which will create a lot of IO (I think you could prove it, measuring it). I would suggest to increase RAM so it non-neap RAM would be enough to get all indices files on that node. This is usually speeding up a lot.

Comment: I don't do any real warming up, is there any settings I can add to do some sort of automated warm up? Or do you think it would help to warm up with arbitrary values, like is elastic search smart enough to and cached filters together to fulfill future requests?

Comment: no, elastic isn't smart enough to warm perfectly for any possible needs. In fact you need to warm him with those filters and after some time those filters will be faster. So, I would recommend to just run similar queries for some time on the cluster, after this one filters let's say from 1 to 1e7 will be warmed and will be executed much faster

Comment: For #2, I think the problem is actually that I'm running in GKE and I was liking the container memory to 15 GB, assuming the os page cache lives in the container and not the host, then I'm probably starving the os page cache. I'm increasing that now and debating adding index.store.cache settings to cache the doc values.